# CentOS how to delete files in |MOUNT_POINT|

Tags: centos, mount

When I was looking for big files that were using a lot of space on my CentOS VM, I noticed the following:

```
/home/|MOUNT_POINT|/backup/11-17-14/custom/home/user1.tar.gz
/home/|MOUNT_POINT|/backup/11-17-14/custom/home/user2.tar.gz
/home/|MOUNT_POINT|/backup/11-17-14/custom/home/user3.tar.gz
/home/|MOUNT_POINT|/backup/11-17-14/custom/home/user4.tar.gz
/home/|MOUNT_POINT|/backup/11-17-14/custom/home/user5.tar.gz
/home/|MOUNT_POINT|/backup/11-17-14/custom/home/user6.tar.gz
```

I would like to delete these backup files, however I see no `/home/backup/`, nor `/backup/` and I can't enter the `|MOUNT_POINT|` directory itself. What can I do?

Comment: Exactly how did you try to enter |MOUNT_POINT|?

Comment: a path with | ? ummmm

Comment: I tried entering with `cd |MOUNT_POINT|`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some possibilities:

To `cd` into the directory, use one of the following:

- `cd '/home/|MOUNT_POINT|'`
- `cd /home/\|MOUNT_POINT\|`

To remove the stuff:

```
rm /home/\|MOUNT_POINT\|/backup/11-17-14/custom/home/user?.tar.gz
```